# How to change the value of a user field through Restfull?

Tags: users, 9

I can’t change the value of field_motherid field through restfall. GET running, PUT disabled, PATCH enabled and configured. When I do GET there is no user field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the user rest resource is enabled and `PATCH` requests are configured, also that the requesting user is authenticated to update the user, then:

send a `PATCH` request to: https://example.com/user/$uid?_format=json

Where `$uid` is the user id to update (e.g 12)

The request body should look something like this (json format):

```
{ "field_motherid":
  [
    {"value": "new_value"}
  ]
}
```